# spring boot how to set securitycontext for scheduled task to call secured method?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to use a `@scheduled` task to update some data in my database.

```
@Scheduled()
public void update() {
  sync()
}

public void sync() {
   if (SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
      .getAuthentication().getAuthorities().stream.matchAny(r-> ROLE_ADMIN)) {
...
    } else {
    ...
    }
}
```

The `securityContext` is `null` once the scheduled task runs. Without removing permission validation, how do I set the `securityContext` of the scheduled task to Admin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `SecurityContext` is stored in the `ThreadLoacal`. You can use the following codes to create a fake admin user and set it to the `SecurityContext` before running `sync()` :

```java
List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();

//This is the permission that the admin should have. It depends on your application security configuration.
grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")); 


// Here it does not matter what values username and password are. 
// Just ensure this user has the the Admin GrantedAuthority and his account is enabled 
User user = new User("admin", "password", true, true, true, true, grantedAuthorities);

Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, user.getPassword(), user.getAuthorities());
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

If the thread that executes sync() is dedicated for the scheduled task to run only , you can keep that thread to has this fake admin user. Otherwise , you need to clear this fake admin user from the `ThreadLocal` after running sync() :

```java
SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
```

Comment: I wonder weather `.clearContext()` is better or worse than `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null)`?

Comment: is User an 
        org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties 

instance ?